# Spare gap in html email in Outlook Windows 10

Tags: html, email, outlook

Hy!

I am new at this and trying to write my first html email code.
I have an issue with html inline email code exactly in Outlook and on Windows 10.
It makes unnecessary gap between two td's starting with td containing the img and until the end. https://codepen.io/kribits/pen/jOOYNmv .
Already tried some tips and tricks like changing to display: block; and separating those two td's with individual   tags, but it doesn't helped. Really searching for some helpful answer.
[The big gap][2]

Here is the code:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style color: #EC6700;></style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Mobilly signature</title>
    <style>
        u + #body a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-weight: inherit;
            line-height: inherit;
        }
       a {
            color: #EC6700 !important;
        }
    </style>
<!--   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /> -->
</head>
    <body id="body">
<table>
    <tbody height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
        style="box-sizing: border-box; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr style="box-sizing: border-box; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <td>
                <span
                    style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; margin: 0;">Ar
                    cieņu,</span>
              <br>
                <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; line-height:20px;">
                    <b>Vārds Uzvārds</b><br>Zīmola vadītājs<br>SIA Company<br>Address<br>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td
                style="display:inline-block; box-sizing:border-box; line-height:21px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; width:75px; height:75px;">
                <img src="" alt="logo">
            </td>
            <td style="display: inline-block; width: 25px;"></td>
            <td
                style="display:inline-block; line-height:21px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; border-collapse: collapse; text-decoration: none !important;">
                <div style="display:inline-block; color: #EC6700; "
                     ><span
                        style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none !important;"> <a href="vards.uzvards@mobilly.lv"  style="text-decoration:none;"> vards.uzvards&#64;mobilly.lv</a></span><br>
                    <a
                        href="https://mobilly.lv/" target="blank" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span
                            style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">www.mobilly.lv</span></a><br><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none !important;"> 
                  <a href="" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">+371 66047706</a></span><br><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mobilly.lv/" target="blank"
                        style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span
                            style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">Facebook | </span></a><a
                        href="https://www.instagram.com/mobilly.lv/?hl=en" target="blank"
                        style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span
                            style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">Instagram | </span></a><a
                        href="https://twitter.com/mobilly?lang=en" target="blank"
                        style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span
                            style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">Twitter |</span></a><a
                        href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/mobillysia" target="blank"
                        style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"> <span
                            style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">LinkedIn</span></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <p> Šis e-pasta sūtījums, kā arī visi tam pievienotie dokumenti ir konfidenciāli un paredzēti vienīgi uzrādītajam adresātam. Sūtījuma satura neakceptēta izpaušana, izplatīšana vai izmainīšana ir aizliegta un var būt prettiesiska. Ja Jūs neesat šī sūtījuma adresāts, lūdzu, informējiet par to nosūtītāju un izdzēsiet sūtījumu no sistēmas.</p>
            <p>
 The information in this e-mail is confidential. It is intended solely for the addressee and access to the e-mail by anyone else is unauthorised. If you are not a named recipient, any disclosure, copying, reliance on it is prohibited and may be unlawful. If the notice is not intended for you, please notify the sender immediately and delete the e-mail.</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
</html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTg3i.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HwGf.jpg
````

Comment: That just a web page, where is the creating the email part?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand Your question. 
At the end of problem description there is also code which will be used for email.

Comment: I presumed you were triggering the actual email creation using code, but if this is just a template then my question doesn't apply?  Also, are you getting a different result in Outlook compared to just viewing the HTML output on that weblink you added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. Wrapped your two column section inside another table and aligned them left. That did fix your issue!

https://codepen.io/ShuvojitDas/pen/wvayQdq

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <style color: #EC6700;></style>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <title>Mobilly signature</title>
   <style>
   u+#body a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
   }
   a {
      color: #EC6700 !important;
   }
   </style>   
   <!--   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /> -->
</head>
<body id="body">
   <table style="border-spacing:0;text-align:left;" align="left">
      <tr style="border-collapse: collapse;">
         <td>
            <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; margin: 0;">Ar
               cieņu,</span>
            <br>
            <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; line-height:20px;">
               <b>Vārds Uzvārds</b><br>Zīmola vadītājs<br>SIA Company<br>Address<br>
            </p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table align="left">
               <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-right:24px; line-height:21px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; width:75px; height:75px;">
                     <img src="https://mobilly.lv/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Mobilly-Hor-161x161-1.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="logo">
                  </td>
                  <td align="left" style="line-height:21px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; font-size:14px; border-collapse: collapse; text-decoration: none !important;">
                     <div style="color: #EC6700; "><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none !important;"> <a href="vards.uzvards@mobilly.lv" style="text-decoration:none;"> vards.uzvards&#64;mobilly.lv</a></span><br>
                        <a href="https://mobilly.lv/" target="blank" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">www.mobilly.lv</span></a><br><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none !important;">
                           <a href="" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">+371 66047706</a></span><br><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mobilly.lv/" target="blank" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">Facebook | </span></a><a href="https://www.instagram.com/mobilly.lv/?hl=en" target="blank" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">Instagram | </span></a><a href="https://twitter.com/mobilly?lang=en" target="blank" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"><span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">Twitter |</span></a><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/mobillysia" target="blank" style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;"> <span style="color: #EC6700; text-decoration:none;">LinkedIn</span></a>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <div>
               <p> Šis e-pasta sūtījums, kā arī visi tam pievienotie dokumenti ir konfidenciāli un paredzēti vienīgi uzrādītajam adresātam. Sūtījuma satura neakceptēta izpaušana, izplatīšana vai izmainīšana ir aizliegta un var būt prettiesiska. Ja Jūs neesat šī sūtījuma adresāts, lūdzu, informējiet par to nosūtītāju un izdzēsiet sūtījumu no sistēmas.</p>
               <p>
                  The information in this e-mail is confidential. It is intended solely for the addressee and access to the e-mail by anyone else is unauthorised. If you are not a named recipient, any disclosure, copying, reliance on it is prohibited and may be unlawful. If the notice is not intended for you, please notify the sender immediately and delete the e-mail.</p>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, presuming you are getting the same result in Outlook as viewing the HTML output directly in the weblink, it's your paragraph `<p>` tags creating the gap and has nothing to do with the table.

A paragraph tag creates a blank like before and after the paragraph.

It becomes more obvious to see if you turn the borders on in your table temporarily by changing border="0" to border = "1".